# how to examine database in the middle of a Django test run?

Tags: django, django-testing

I'm trying to be a good programmer and use Django's testing facility.  things are going pretty well, but I would like to be able to examine the database when I stop the program in the debugger.  It looks like the database work that I do in my setUp routines is wrapped in a transaction, so I can't see it from another session (I'm using a PostgreSQL back-end).

I've done some playing around and I *don't* have TransactionMiddleware installed.  I tried decorating my functions with django.db.transactions.commit_on_success, but that is not helping.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly using [TransactionTestCase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/testing/#django.test.TransactionTestCase) instead of TestCase might help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `django.test.TestCase`, [Django wraps each test in a transaction](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#django.test.TestCase), which is rolled back at the end of the test. You should subclass `TransactionTestCase` instead.